# show a text per day

Tags: php, sql

i have a table that have too many text record . ( For example `1000` record )

my table structure look like below :

```
ID          |         Text
---------------------------------------
 1          |       My Test Text 1
 2          |       My Test Text 2
```

i want show a record per day, have any idea about this ?

thanks

Comment: Er... yeah... there is a date associated with each row, or you really just want to grab a record once in 24 hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

order by rand with a seed of todays date   `ORDER BY RAND(CURDATE())` or   `$date = date('Y-m-d') ;`  and then use   `...ORDER BY RAND($date)`

Comment: Wow. I had no idea you could put a date inside `RAND()`. Too lazy to try it right now but I'll take your word for it - that rocks.

Comment: yeah its handy to make things random by the hour or day.

Comment: Another approch could be something like this:
SELECT Text FROM table WHERE id = DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), activated)
Might be possible to add some kind of MOD on rows to make it start over when last id is reache.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

That will fetch a random record. Cache it with PHP with a 24 hour lifespan. Every time this page is loaded, PHP should check for the cache file and the expire time. If the cache is expired, make the new query, re-cache. Rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 2):

RAND() function works in a defined way so you can use a seed to generate a random selection on the table. For the purpose you can use the Current date as seed and the query will be look like 
SELECT Text From Table_Name ORDER BY RAND(CURDATE()) LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

for that you need to add column in table to store date on which data has been inserted.

and then you can always write query to get data as per date..

Comment: no because i want if i have 20 record, from this 20 record show a text per day

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to sort randomly and limit your results to 1, as you have no date column.

```
SELECT text FROM yourTable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

(assuming MySQL)

Answer (score 0):

You could write (or find) a function that would generate a pseudo-random integer (some type of very high-collision hash) based on the date.  Use that to `SELECT Text WHERE ID = ?`.  That way you don't have to store any additional data.  Of course, you would have to make the integer bound in the range of *n* to *m*, where *n* is your lowest ID and *m* is your highest.

Answer (score 0):

because you don't have date in it, my suggestion is to **use text file to store what ID is shown yesterday** (some **UNTESTED** quick code to get you started):

```
<?php
$tempfile = '/path/to/file/yesterday_id.txt';

list($yesterday_id, $yesterday_date) = explode("\t", file_get_contents( $tempfile ));
$today = date('Y-m-d');
if( $yesterday_date <> $today)
{
   $yesterday_id++;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE id = '$yesterday_id'";
$rs = mysql_query( $sql );
if( $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{
   echo $r['text'];
   file_put_contents($tempfile, "{$yesterday_id}\t{$today}");
}
else
{
   echo "text not found.";
}
?>
```